# cyrillized words read from database with php

Tags: php, cyrillic

Why when I'm reading a cyrillic text from database it's ok , but when I put this text in select-option menu I get strange symbols

http://prikachi.com/images/813/6589813g.jpg
http://prikachi.com/images/811/6589811I.jpg

I think that I put everywhere to be utf-8 but I don't know ...

in my html I use :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: Check what target table field, where you store all the strings also  have following collation:  utf8_general_ci

Comment: The problem here is caused by the cherset used to either insert data in the DB (should be utf-8-general) and the charset set when you connect to the db. MySQLi, PDO and mysql_* all have functions to set default charset when connecting

Comment: Also, before executing any queries, try yo execute following one:  SET NAMES utf8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most likely you're not using the same charset (utf-8) *everywhere* so your data gets messed up at some point. depending on what exactly you're doing, you'll have to change/add one or more of the following points (maybe it's the `SET CHARSET`/`mysql_set_charset` you forgot):

- tell MySQL to use utf-8. to do this, add this to your my.cnf:

  > ```
  > collation_server = utf8_unicode_ci
  > character_set_server = utf8
  > ```
- before interacting with mysql, send this two querys:

  > ```
  > SET NAMES 'utf8';
  > CHARSET 'utf8';
  > ```

  or, alternatively, let php do this after opening the connection:

  > ```
  > mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn); // when using the mysql_-functions
  > mysqli::set_charset('utf8') // when using mysqli
  > ```
- set UTF-8 as the default charset for your database

  > ```
  > CREATE DATABASE `my_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
  > ```
- do the same for tables:

  > ```
  > CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  >   -- ...
  > ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
  > ```
- assuming the client is a browser, serve your content as utf-8 and the the correct header:

  > ```
  > header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  > ```

  to be really sure the browser understands, add a meta-tag:

  > ```
  > <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  > ```
- and, last but not least, tell the browser to submit forms using utf-8

  > ```
  > <form accept-charset="utf-8" ...>
  > ```

Comment: This seems very thorough

Comment: thaks a lot , i really missed some of them

Comment: mysqli::set_charset('utf8') <<< Does't that load the preset charset first and then as soon as the connection is established, it loads the utf8 charset? In that case that would be a performance issue. So what is the root of the charset, where do I change it for ever, without adjusting it for every connection?